# How to extract unique data from cells in a single column with thousands of similar values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I have a single column in an Excel sheet with around 25,000 cells (numbers). Most of them are identical that in the end there are only - I guess - maybe 200 different numbers.

[image: Postleitzahlen]

Is there a way to extract them? In the end, I want a list with every entry only occurring once:

```
...
15745
15746
15748
...
```

I played around with a lot of Excel features, including the new [grouping option](https://superuser.com/a/540938/189848) - but most of them only work with tables of **two** or more columns.

I have Excel 2013, Excel 2007 and Libre Office Calc 3.6 available. Any ideas?

---

***Update***: Yes, I want that list in an Excel sheet or similar tools. Anything that allows further tabular processing. CSV would be okay, too.

Comment: you want a list where?  in excel?  in a single cell as strings?

Comment: yes in excel. updated the question and added clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [Filter for unique values or remove duplicate values](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx#BMlearn_more)?

- Select the range of cells, or make sure the active cell is in a table.
- On the **Data** tab, in the **Sort & Filter** group, click **Advanced**.

[image]

- In the **Advanced Filter** dialog box, do one of the following:

  1. To filter the range of cells or table in place, click **Filter the list, in-place**.
  2. To copy the results of the filter to another location, do the following:

     - Click **Copy to another location**.
     - In the **Copy to** box, enter a cell reference.
     - Alternatively, click **Collapse Dialog** Button image to temporarily hide the dialog box, select a cell on the worksheet, and then press **Expand Dialog** Button image.
- Select the **Unique records only** check box, and click OK.

The unique values from the selected range are copied to the new location.